# .bat set a variable according to Multi draged and dropped files

Tags: batch, batch-file

How can I set the variables in my .bat file according to the dropped file?

```
Set file=C:\files\movie.mp4
Set folder=C:\files\
```

I want to change this, so when I dragged and dropped a file into .bat the file variable changes to be dragged file path, and folder changes to the file parent directory.

Is that possible?

**EDIT**: *Above problem has been solved thanks to **Keltari** & **DavidPostill***

Now, I am facing problem when I dropped multiple files onto the .bat.
It only executes the first file and don't touch the rest. Though it works if I dropped files one by one.

What should I change to make it work?

My code is

```
SET file=%~1
SET folder=%~dp1

ffmpeg -y -ss 120 -i "%file%" -an -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -t 00:00:010 "%folder%prev001.ts"
ffmpeg -y -ss 300 -i "%file%" -an -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -t 00:00:010 "%folder%prev002.ts"
ffmpeg -y -ss 600 -i "%file%" -an -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -t 00:00:010 "%folder%prev003.ts"
```

Comment: I don't think console applications support drag-and-drop feature, at least by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786623/batch-file-copy-using-1-for-drag-and-drop) from StackOverflow covers how to do it:

Drag & drop is badly implemented for batch files.
The names are quoted, if a space is present, but not if a special character is found, like &,;^

For spaces only in your filenames, you need to change your code only a bit.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO "%~1"
COPY "%~1" "%CD%\test\" /Y /S 
REN "%CD%\mob\*.png" "%CD%\test\test.png"
7za u -tzip "%appdata%\.virto\pack.zip" "test" -r
```

`%~1` expands always to an unquoted version, so can always quote them in a safe way.

`"c:\Docs and sets" -> %~1 -> c:\Docs and sets -> "%~1" -> "c:\Docs and sets"
c:\Programs -> %~1 -> c:\Programs -> "%~1" -> "c:\Programs"`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Hoping that you can help with the new problem I am facing right now. Post has been edited.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2132188, Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31358421/2861476) could help you.